# Draw Quad and Cubic Bezier in Cocos2d v3 on IOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to draw a Cubic/Quad Bezier with Cocos2d v3. I looked at CCDrawNode but no change. Does anyone know a way around? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

finally, I found the solution: https://github.com/njt1982/CCDrawNode-Bezier

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in Cocos2d 3.3:

```
// blue test
auto bluN = DrawNode::create();
//Draw a blue quadratic bezier curve
Color4F blue(0, 0, 1, 1);
bluN->drawCubicBezier(Vec2(0.0, 0.0), Vec2(_visibleSize.height, 0.0), Vec2(_visibleSize.height, _visibleSize.height), Vec2(0.0,_visibleSize.height), 18, blue);
_hudLayer->addChild(bluN);
```

This creates a perfect semi-circle (half-circle).

Chris

Comment: This is Cocos2D-X, not Cocos2D.