# drawing bezier curves in Cocos2d v3.4.. no more ccDrawQuadBezier

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, bezier

In Cocos2d-iphone 3.4 I want to draw a bezier curve and be able to manipulate it by dragging points on it.

It looks like in previous versions of Cocos2d I would have used: ccDrawQuadBezier
ccDrawCubicBezier
ccDrawCatmullRom
ccDrawCardinalSpline

These don't appear to be available in Cocos2d 3.4

Comment: Note that https://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/ tells us that it's no longer called `cocos2d-iphone`, but is now `cocos2d-spritebuilder`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Draw Quad and Cubic Bezier in Cocos2d v3 on IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143084/draw-quad-and-cubic-bezier-in-cocos2d-v3-on-ios)